# If statement over pandas.series and append result to list

Tags: python, pandas

i'm trying to build a few list made from results. Could you tell me why this results is empty?

I'm not looking for sollution with numpy, that's why originally i'll create > 50 list, later save it to CSV.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data={"Country":["USA","Germany","Russia","Poland"], 
"Capital":["Washington","Berlin","Moscow","Warsaw"], "Region": 
["America","Europe","Europe",'Europe']})


America = []

if (df1['Region']=='America').all():
America.append(df1)

print(America)
```

Comment: are you sure you are using .all function at the right place, its placed near the if condition paranthesis

Comment: When I'm using, for example .any() - I'll get whole dataframe, isntead first row :(
I'm not sure if .all() function here is a good choice - i'm looking for working solution ;-)

Comment: Can you share the code in an online compiler where we can play around.

Comment: I hope You mean something like this https://onlinegdb.com/S1jX5XrdQ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your expression `df1['Region']=='America'` gives a so-called boolean mask ([docs on boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)). A boolean mask is a pandas `Series` of `True` and `False` whose index is lined up with the index of `df1`.

It's easy to get your expected values once you get used to boolean indexing:

```
df1[df1['Region']=='America']
  Country     Capital   Region
0     USA  Washington  America
```

If you are interested in keeping entire rows, don't bother manually building a python list; that would complicate your work immensely compared to sticking to pandas. You can store the rows in a new DataFrame:

```
# Use df.copy() here so that changing America won't change df1
America = df1[df1['Region']=='America'].copy()
```

#### Why `if (df1['Region']=='America').all():` didn't work

The `Series.all()` method checks whether *all* values in the Series are True. What you need to do here is to check *each* row for your condition df1['Region']=='America', and keep only those rows that match this condition (if I understand you correctly).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about what you want.
If you want to add the whole dataframe to the list if 'America' is in region :

```
for region in df1.Region :
    if region == 'America':
        America.append(df1)
```

If you want to add the element from each list wich is at same index than 'America' in 'Region' list :

```
count = 0
for region in df1.Region :
    if region == 'America':
        America.append(df1.Country[count])
        America.append(df1.Capital[count])
    count += 1
```

Does this answer the question ?